# How to show all tables with column header as "Text" in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to show all tables in mysql I have used the following command.

```
 show tables;`
```

[image]

I don't want to display db name in the column header.How to display with "Text" as column header in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `information_schema` for this.

```
SELECT 
table_name from information_schema.tables where 
table_schema = 'extdirectnode';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a query against the information_schema database, like this:

```
SELECT t.table_name AS `Text`
  FROM information_schema.tables t
 WHERE t.table_schema = 'extdirectnode'
 ORDER BY t.table_name
```